# Zxing doesn't scan 1d bar codes and doesn't shows red line

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, zxing

I'm trying to develop an App witch get 1d bar codes number using Zxing lib. I download the lib and I compiled it with ant. Them, I include the core.jar into my app source.

Now, I wan't to get the number of the bar code, and I use the following java code:

```
    Intent barscan = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    barscan.putExtra("SCAN_WIDTH", 300);
    barscan.putExtra("SCAN_HEIGHT", 200);

    barscan.putExtra("RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS", 3000L);
    barscan.putExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Custom prompt to scan a product");

    barscan.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(barscan, 0);
```

But with this code I have some problems:

- I can't see the red line across the screen.
- I want to scan the barcode and return, but that only happens with QR codes. With 1d bar codes nothing happen.

What is wrong?

Thank everyone for your time!

Answer (score 1):

(I answered already on the mailing list.)

If you don't see a red line, then you are not using Barcode Scanner to handle the Intent. I don't know what app is handling it, but it's not something from here.
Use Intent.setPackage() to restrict to Barcode Scanner's package of com.google.zxing.client.android. Better yet, use the provided IntentIntegrator code.

Comment: You are right. The intent is handle by google googles. I installed the barcode scanner in my device and now i can select the handler. But it isn't that I want. I will try with intent.setpackage... Thank you